# Using $cookies.get in angular config file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

So i am trying to access cookies in my angular config file but i keep getting injection errors.

I have looked at many resources but still can not get it to work. please help

here is my `routes.js`

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Route configuration for the DashApp module.
 */
angular.module('DashApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$cookies',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $cookies) {

       if($cookies.get('email') ===undefined){
          console.log('user not logged in');
          //this doesnt work, injecting $cookies causes error 
       }


        // For unmatched routes
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        // Application routes
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
            })
            .state('account', {
                url: '/account',
                templateUrl: 'templates/account.html'
            });
    }
]);
```

Comment: just a note, it works if I dont inject $cookies. any ideas why?

Comment: You dont have angular-cookie file in right way, try copy `script src` of cookies file from your console and paste it in your url bar

Comment: @nivas, sorry, i dont understand. what? the same code works in my controller.

Comment: you don't have angular-cookie.js file? and its working

Comment: Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Modules -- Loading Dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

Comment: @georgeawg, thanks for the informative links, i dug around a bit and tried a few injections with no luck.. do you know how I can accomplish my $cookies injection?

Comment: Use the $cookies service in run blocks. Trying to inject it into config blocks will give [$injector unpr errors](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$cookies). What are you trying to accomplish with the $cookies service in a config block?